# htaccess deny all by ip address except those in united states?

Tags: .htaccess, ip, ip-address

I have a local Web site that I would like to tighten access to only those within the United States; or perhaps only within Florida. It's a Word Press site that has gotten hacked due to some weak code. I've seen two sources of IP address lists for .htaccess "allow deny" control by IP Address.

IP by Country/Continents:
http://www.countryipblocks.net/continents/

Wizcrafts List:
http://www.wizcrafts.net/htaccess-blocklists.html

What is the best approach for blocking everything except United States traffic? How would you approach the deny/allow? Would you deny other Countries or try to allow only the U.S.?

Thanks for any comments, Jeff

Comment: You could program it to block ip addresses but any hacker would be able to get around this. Especially considering Florida is the source of much of the worlds malicious software, something to do with the Mafia being there.

Comment: What's this about the Mafia? LOL, Florida can't be the source of the worlds malicious software. But, you are right. With any proxy server inside the US, a hacker could change their IP address.  What I'm trying to do is limit the number of attacks, and/or make it more difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add [this list](http://www.ipdeny.com/ipblocks/data/countries/us.zone) to the .htaccess located on the root folder of your server.
It will only allow connections from the US.

ex .htaccess  file:

allow from IP
203.31.234.0/24
129.230.176.0/20
etc...

Comment: How are they sure this list is comprehensive? The last thing I want to do is lose a USA customer because I had not allowed them in.

Comment: @Doug - I agree. It may not be worth the loss. Perhaps it's better to deny certain countries as problems arise.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `deny from All` in order to forbid access to your site!

In  [countryipblocks](http://www.countryipblocks.net/)  you can download all IPs from the area you want and add `allow from IP` to your .htaccess file! so only those IPs can access to your site!

**Edit**: Remember you can add IP range instead of one IP!
I downloaded .htacees from that site, and that was ok!